# Pointed Convex cone: one-to-one correspondence extreme rays - extreme points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Hoi, let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space with inner product $\left\langle .\right\rangle$. Let $\Gamma\subset V$ and $\Gamma \neq \left\{0\right\}$ a pointed convex cone. (Pointed means $\Gamma \cap -\Gamma = \left\{0\right\}$)

I want to show there exists a hyperplane $H$ through $0$ and $x_0\in \Gamma, x_0\neq 0$ such that the extreme points of the convex set $C:=\Gamma\cap (x_0+H)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the extreme rays of $\Gamma$.

I know there exists $z\in \Gamma\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ such that  $\left\langle z,w\right\rangle >0$ for all $w\in \Gamma\setminus  \left\{0\right\}$. Then if we consider the hyperplane $H$ with normal $\textbf{n} =z$, then $H$ is a hyperplane through 0 such that $H\cap \Gamma = \left\{0\right\}$

Then i suppose for $x_0$ we can take some $x_0 = \lambda z$ with $\lambda >0$ and then the rest seems intuitively clear. (but this is my Euclidean intuition speaking). But how do I make this precise?

Thanks for any help, or suggestions.

Comment: I think the usual term for what you seem to call pointed is salient. I'm also confused about you writing $x_0+H$: If $x_0\in H$, $x_0+H=H$ right?

Comment: No, I dont think its called salient. Its not about finding a $H$ for which is does not work. Recall $x_0\in \Gamma\setminus \left\{0\right\}$. Since the hyperplane $H$ i am talking about is such that $H\cap \Gamma = \left\{0\right\}$ that situation does not occur. I know the hyper-plane $H$, and $x_0$ I describe work. I just want to properly prove it..

Comment: I see, you mean to say there exists a hyperplane $H$ through $0$ and there exists $x_0\in\Gamma$. I thought you meant that there exists a hyperplane through $0$ and $x_0$ for some $x_0\in\Gamma$.

Comment: Yes. Like you mentioned a few seconds ago: take $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $x,y\geq 0$. Then $x_0 = (1,1) \in \Gamma$, and the line $H = \text{span} (1,-1)$ works.

Comment: I updated my answer, I don't know if you got a notification for that. Does it suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I will carefully read it. I realy like some of the ideas presented in it. Actually that z with the property I mentioned does exist for pointed convex cones. I had to prove this in a few steps in some exercise previous to this one. Its probably a building block for proving this, and it helps to show that such hyperplane $H$ with the property $H\cap \Gamma =$ {0} exists.

Comment: Surely such a $z$ doesn't exist for $\{(x,y)|y>0\mbox{ or }(y=0\mbox{ and }x\geq 0)\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. Suitably this cone also doesn't admit any hyperplane $H$ such that $H\cap\Gamma=\{0\}$.

Comment: Actually it does :P. If we talk about normal inproduct this is easily verified. Take in your first example $z = (0,1)$.

Comment: And $H = (x,0)$

Comment: No it doesn't: $\langle (0,1),(1,0)\rangle=0$ for instance and $H\cap\{(x,y)|y>0\mbox{ or }(y=0\mbox{ and }x\geq 0)\} = \{(x,y)|y=0\mbox{ and }x\geq 0\}\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: If we take $\Gamma = \{(x,y)|y>0\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$ (note the 0 must be in $\Gamma$). Then it is a pointed convex cone. Also  if $H = (x,0)$ we have $H\cap \Gamma  = \{0\}$ (so that is with $z = (0,1)$ as normal).

Comment: But I took $\Gamma = \{(x,y)|y>0\}\cup\{(x,0)|x\geq 0\}$ which is also a pointed convex cone. For my $\Gamma$ there is no such $z$ nor is there such a $H$.

Comment: you're right. This is re-solved if one assumes that Γ must be closed. However this is not assumed in the exercise...I'm confused. ( I think that its implicitly assumed, although not stated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a $z\in\Gamma\backslash\{0\}$ such that $\langle z,w\rangle>0$ for all $w\in\Gamma\backslash\{0\}$ does not exist for general pointed cones, your result follows if we assume it does.

Let $H=z^\perp$ and let $x_0=z$.
The set of rays in $\Gamma$ is $R=(\Gamma\backslash\{0\})/\sim$, where $x\sim y$ iff $x=ay$ for some $a\in(0,\infty)$. We will denote the ray containing $x$ by $[x]=\{ax|a\in(0,\infty)\}$.

Now define the map $\phi\colon R\to (H+z)\cap\Gamma\colon[x]\mapsto\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}x$.
First of all, $\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}x\in [x]\subset\Gamma$ since $\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}>0$. Secondly $\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}x\in H+z$ since
$$\left\langle\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}x-z,z\right\rangle = \frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}\langle x,z\rangle-\langle z,z\rangle =0.$$
Thirdly, $\phi$ is well defined since $\phi([ax]) = \frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle ax,z\rangle} ax = \frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}x = \phi([x])$.

Now I claim that $\phi$ is a bijection. First we prove injectivity: Suppose $\phi([x])=\phi([y])$, then $\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle} x = \frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle y,z\rangle}y$ and hence $x = \frac{\langle x,z\rangle}{\langle y,z\rangle}y$. Since $\frac{\langle x,z\rangle}{\langle y,z\rangle}>0$, this proves $x\sim y$ and hence $[x]=[y]$.
Secondly we prove surjectivity: Let $x\in(H+z)\cap\Gamma$. Since $x\in H+z$, $0=\langle x-z,z\rangle = \langle x,z\rangle -\langle z,z\rangle$, thus $\langle x,z\rangle = \langle z,z\rangle$ and we have $\phi([x]) = \frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}x = x$.

Now all that remains to show is that $[x]$ is extremal if and only if $\phi([x])$ is. We do this by contraposition. Suppose $\phi([x]) = t v+(1-t)w$ for some $v\neq w\in (H+z)\cap\Gamma$ and some $t\in(0,1)$. Then $[x] = [\phi([x])] = [tv+(1-t)w] = t[v]+(1-t)[w]$. Furthermore $[v]\neq[w]$ since $\phi([v])=v\neq w=\phi([w])$.

Now suppose $[x]=t[v]+(1-t)[w]$ for some $[v]\neq[w]\in R$ and some $t\in(0,1)$.
Then $x = av+bw$ for some $a,b> 0$. Hence $$\phi([x]) = \frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}x = \frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}(av+bw) = a\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}v + b\frac{\langle z,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}w$$
which
$$=a\frac{\langle v,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}\phi([v])+b\frac{\langle w,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}\phi([w]).$$
Since $a\frac{\langle v,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}+b\frac{\langle w,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle} = \frac{\langle av+bw,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle} = \frac{\langle x,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}=1$ and since both $a\frac{\langle v,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}$ and $b\frac{\langle w,z\rangle}{\langle x,z\rangle}$ are positive this concludes the argument.